# Repast Simphony 2.0 (Eclipse mod) - Where would you configure or set a maximum "tick count" value?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

This question is strictly for the Repast Simphony 2.0 mod for Eclipse:

My model runs indefinitely (people meandering about). I am trying to set a maximum tick-count so, I can create reports and compare changes that occur in a constant amount of time.

I need to figure out the best place (and how) to access each "tick count" iteration, and update the code to STOP once it reaches a certain amount of elapsed time.

If anyone has any experience with Repast Simphony, I would love to hear ANY advice you have!

Thanks,

Z@K!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static final double MAX_ITERATIONS = 1200;

RunEnvironment model_core = RunEnvironment.getInstance();
model_core.endAt(MAX_ITERATIONS);
```

The answer lies in the `public void endAt(double tick)` method of the `RunEnvironment` object.